# How do I buy gold from the Diablo 3 real money auction house?

Tags: diablo-iii

I can not find gold in the search drop down in Diablo 3's auction house.

- I click gold on the real money side.
- Text box shows `x 100,000`.
- Selecting various options doesn't return results

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

You may see the behavior you describe if gold or commodity auctions have been disabled.  Instead of popping up a dialog and notifying you that this functionality is currently disabled, usually you'll get an unhelpful error message or no search results instead.

Although at the time this question was asked, gold and commodity auctions were not available on the real money auction house, they have since been added.  In the US, commodities became available for trade as part of [patch 1.0.3b](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6648349/Patch_103b_Now_Live-7_10_2012) on 7/10/2012, and gold became available [in a hotfix](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/6008721977) on 7/12.

Answer (score 1):

As of 1.0.3b Build 10485 Patch, gems, gold and etc are now enabled in the RMAH